# Present a ViewController although UIAlertController is in the view Hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, uialertcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

I want to `presentViewController` when an `alertController` is presented.

I want such as if user presses the Ok button now i want to show the `ViewController` from AppDelegate on PushNotification.

I came to know on SO that `UIAlertController` is presented on different thread so want to present the `ViewController` after user presses Ok Button and moves on to main thread as below:

```
func presentRScreenFromRootViewController()
{

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rsh") as! R_SVC
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(rViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    });

}
```

But I get warning as:

> ```
>  Attempt to present <BB.R_SVC: 0x15b983600>  on
>  <SWRevealViewController: 0x15652df00> which is already presenting
>  <UIAlertController: 0x15b4f2dd0>
> ```

This is because the viewcontroller is presenting alertcontroller.Other times its working well..My rootViewController changes and moves to next screen..But when there is UIAlertController i get warning as attempt to present viewcontroller which is not in the view hierarchy

**What am i doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

when creating UIAlertController, place you VCpresenting code in the an UIAlertAction like so

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "your title", message "move to next VC?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let action: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "yes move to next VC", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {action -> Void in 
    let rViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rsh") as! R_SVC
    self.presentViewController(rViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) })
alert.addAction(defaultAction)

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

edit: Maybe try [Dismiss all UIAlertControllers currently presented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636640/dismiss-all-uialertcontrollers-currently-presented?rq=1).

Comment: this issue arises all at runtime...for e.g if user gets alertviewcontroller without getting push notification ......and alertviewcontroller is still alive

Comment: did you try this method? it will close your UIAlertController then execute the code to present VC.

Comment: did you see my comment clearly ??? but dustin is there any way i can dismiss if there are alertcontroller currently in the view

Comment: no i am sorry but your comments aren't clear...dismiss? dismiss what? the AlertController? This method will present Alert, which currently has one button. when pressed...Alert will be dismissed and R_SVC will be presented.

Comment: no i want alertcontroller to dismiss if there are any presented